# Confusion while extracting required part of a file using awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a script making use of awk,sed,grep and other shell features.

I have stuck at a place so need your help ...

This is the `input` file for the my  problem

```
udit@udit-Dabba ~/ah $ cat decrypt.txt
 60 00 00 00 00 17 3a 20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02  *00 00 e0 f9 6a 61 61 6e
 65 6b 61 68 61 6e 67 61  79 65 77 6f 64 69 6e* 00
 00 00 03 29
```

My purpose is to extract `00 00 e0 f9 6a 61 61 6e
     65 6b 61 68 61 6e 67 61  79 65 77 6f 64 69 6e` from the above mentioned file
,also marked between `*`'s above

Although obvious but these `*`'s are shown to clear the situation here , they are not actually present in the file.

The last five units of the file as shown above are ..

`00 00 00 03 29`

These `00` are simple pad bytes and `03` specify their pad length

and now here is the part of script to extract the required part :

```
size=`wc -w decrypt.txt`
padlen=3 // calculated by some other mechanism


awk -v size=$size -v padlen=$padlen 'BEGIN {RS=" ";ORS=" ";} {if (NR > 40 
&& NR <=size-padlen-2) print $0}' decrypt.txt | sed '1,1s/ //'
```

**output :**

```
00 00 e0 f9 6a 61 61 6e
65 6b 61 68 61 6e 67 61  79 65 77 6f 64 69
```

**My problem :**
last unit `6e` missing

Also tried through terminal ...

`size=68,padlen=3` so loop should go from `NR=40 to NR<=63`

```
udit@udit-Dabba ~/ah $  awk 'BEGIN {RS=" ";ORS=" ";} {if (NR > 40 && NR <= 65)
print $0}' decrypt.txt | sed '1,1s/ //'

00 00 e0 f9 6a 61 61 6e
65 6b 61 68 61 6e 67 61  79 65 77 6f 64 69 6e 00
00
```

Working fine if loop goes upto `65`.So should also work upto `63`

```
udit@udit-Dabba ~/ah $  awk 'BEGIN {RS=" ";ORS=" ";} {if (NR > 40 && NR <= 64)
print $0}' decrypt.txt | sed '1,1s/ //'

00 00 e0 f9 6a 61 61 6e
65 6b 61 68 61 6e 67 61  79 65 77 6f 64 69 6e
```

But what is this ???? when I decrease `65` to `64` , there is loss of two `00` units.Why this is happening ???

Also tried this one but could not find a reason why this weird output.

```
udit@udit-Dabba ~/ah $  awk 'BEGIN {RS="[ \n]";ORS=" ";} {if (NR > 40
&& NR <=65)print $0}' decrypt.txt | sed '1,1s/ //'

0002  00 00 e0 f9 6a 61 61 6e 65 6b 61 68 61 6e 67 61  79 65 77 6f 64
```

Plase help me out ...

May be I have explained the problem more than the required but really need it .

I am new to all these shell and awk things and so there may be a silly mistake which I could not find out .

Please help me on this ..

Thnx in advance ..

**EDIT :**

```
60 00 00 00 00 17 3a 20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02
```

These are fixed 40 units of ipv6 header,will always remain same.

The portion between *'s is of variable length that is why I need to work in that way otherwise it would have been a simple task .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_padlen=3 _length=23

awk '{
  for (i = NF - l - p - 2; i < NF - p - 2; i++)
    printf "%s", ($i (i < NF - p - 2 - 1 ? OFS : ORS))
  }' l="$_length" p="$_padlen" RS=  ORS='\n' decrypt.txt
```

Comment: +1 `RS= ORS='\n'` . That's not in the manual! Much better that `BEGIN {RS="";ORS="\n"}'`  ;-)

Comment: Thanks :) Actually, it is in the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/html_node/Other-Arguments.html#Other-Arguments), but it has its drawbacks.

Comment: I knew about command-line arg setting, but it never occurred to me to set RS and ORS there. Doah! Thanks!

Comment: Hi @UditGupta, the value assigned with the var=value syntax passed as argument is not available in the BEGIN block.

Answer (score 0):

I made some small changes in the code and able to get till 6e*

```
size=68; padlen=3 ;awk -v size=$size -v padlen=$padlen 'BEGIN {RS=" ";ORS=" ";} {if (NR > 40 && NR <=size-padlen-1) print $0}' decrypt.txt | sed '1,1s/ //'
```

I made size as 68 becos wc wis printing the size and file name and you have to remove it when u are passing the same to the awk script.

Note: I havent understood your requirement fully

Comment: sorry for not mentioning before , the part I need to extract is of variable length.Try your code by simply placing `00 00 e0 f9` between *'s. I am sure you won't be able to extract it through this one.Also see my edit .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem as being: discard the first 40 values and the last n values (where n is the padding + 2 i.e. in this case 3 + 2 = 5), this might work:

```
header=40;padding=5;
tr -d '\n' <decrypt.txt |
sed -r 's/\s+/ /g;s/^(\S+\s+){'"$header"'}//;s/(\S+\s*){'"$padding"'}$//'
```

The trick is to unroll the data and then pick the bits you want.